# Specific CSS not working in Cordova app

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova

I have a CSS class which is added by javascript to a div with id to reveal and animate it. It works in the browser but not on Cordova mobile app:

```
#lobbyme {
position: absolute;
background-color: #F4A716;
width: 60%;
top: 10px;
left: 20%;
height: 8%;
padding: 4%;
color: #fff;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0%,0);
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
border-radius: 100px;
opacity: 0;
/* z-index: 0; */
transform: translate3d(0px,0%,0);
}

#lobbyme.animatelobbyme {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,100%,0)!important;
   opacity: 1; 
   transform: translate3d(0px,100%,0)!important;
}
```

I've tried both javascript and refuse to work on mobile:

```
$("#lobbyme").addClass("animatelobbyme");
$("#lobbyme").css({"opacity":"1", "-webkit-transform":"translate3d(0px,100%,0)"});
```

When running
   alert("opacity" +$("#lobbyme").css('opacity')); I still get opacity 0.

Comment: I can confirm that `-webkit-transition` property is causing the issue. But only on this div. Other divs are animated similarly and are fine. Don't know yet how to solve the problem.

Comment: You need to check compatibility with the native webview of the platform(s) you are developing this for, not their browsers. Webviews and browsers have different supports.

Comment: Yea, but I have the exact situation with other divs, animated like this, and they work.

Comment: It's not a cordova problem, it's a webview support problem. Give more details about the device/emulator showing this problem, SO version, etc.